# Error-expected expression before FILE in fputs

Tags: c, syntax-error

Hiiii.
This is my first time doing an little application with C.
I have this problem:

```
void crearCuenta(){
    char usuario[60], contrasenia[20];
    FILE *cuentas;
    
    printf("Usuario: ");
    scanf("%s", usuario);
    printf("Contrasena: ");
    scanf("%s", contrasenia);

    do {
        printf("La ocontrasena debe tener un minimo de 8 caracteres y un maximo de 20: ");
        scanf("%s", contrasenia);
    }while(sizeof(contrasenia)>8 || sizeof(contrasenia)>20);

    cuentas = fopen("saveData.txt", "a");
    if (cuentas == NULL) puts("Error al abrir el archivo. \n");
    fputs(usuario, FILE *cuentas);
    fputs(contrasenia, FILE *cuentas);
    fclose(cuentas);

    printf("Su cuenta ha sido creada exitosamente");
}
```

Error:

```
70 16 [Error] expected expression before 'FILE'
71 21 [Error] expected expression before 'FILE'
```

I don't know what I can do.
Also I tried to do a header file, but for some reason appear that "crearCuenta it's not defined", but I defined it in the header file.
What I can do?

Comment: Please do not post code and other text as images - [reasoning](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question). Copy it as formatted text into the question. Please also ensure to post complete code as a [mre]. As a new user please take the [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: You are using invalid syntax when calling `fputs`. You need to pass in just the variables and not the type of the variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Keylum states, your necessary answer should be: Change `fputs(usuario,FILE *cuentas)` to

```
fputs(usuario,cuentas);
```

and `fputs(contrasenia,FILE *cuentas)` to

```
fputs(contrasenia,cuentas);
```